# Mutiple binding sources within menu/submenu

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a setup where an observable collection is bound to a listview, when a listview item is tapped a hidden stack appears and displays 3 buttons for the user to continue on their page

Menupage:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:dogs="clr-namespace:MBRMobile.ViewModels.Dogs" 
             x:Class="MBRMobile.Views.Dogs.ViewDog">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="ViewListSource"
                      HasUnevenRows="true"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DogItemsSource}"
                      ItemTapped="ListView_Tapped">
                <ListView.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               Text="Name" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               Text="Breed" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="2"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               Text="From" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="3"
                               Text="Intake"
                               FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    </Grid>
                </ListView.Header>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding VisibilityHeight}" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Text="{Binding DogName}" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Text="{Binding DogBreed}" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="2"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Text="{Binding ReceivedFrom}" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="3"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       Text="{Binding IntakeDate}" />
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                             IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"
                                             Grid.Row="1">
                                    <StackLayout.BindingContext>
                                        <dogs:ViewVM />
                                    </StackLayout.BindingContext>
                                    <Button Text="Update"
                                            Command="{Binding UpdateDog_Clicked}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding DogID}"/>
                                    <Button Text="Remove" 
                                            Command="{Binding RemoveDog_Clicked}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding DogID}" />
                                    <Button Text="Schedule"
                                            Command="{Binding ScheduleDog_Clicked}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding DogID}" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The button bound commands are not within DogItemsSource that is bound to the listview, which is throwing a "not found" error in vs. When I throw the

```
                                    <StackLayout.BindingContext>
                                        <dogs:ViewVM />
                                    </StackLayout.BindingContext>
```

which is referencing the Menu's viewmodel, the buttons appear for a few seconds then the buttons disappear. I can only assume because its reloading the page? DogItemsSource and the button commands are all within the same viewmodel and class. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DogItemsSource and the button commands are all within the same viewmodel and class.

You want to set the BindingContext of StackLayout to the ViewModel
because the Button Command set in ViewModel, right? You can simply set like this:

```
// first set the Name of the page to "this"
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         ....
         x:Name="this">

// set the BindingContext to the page's BindingContext
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
    BindingContext="{Binding BindingContext,Source={x:Reference this}}"
    .....
    Grid.Row="1">
```

Then in page's code behind, set the BindingContext of the ViewDog page:

```
    public ViewDog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new ViewDogViewModel();
    }
```

**Now** in StackLayout, the **BindingContext** will be the ViewModel (the same as ViewDog page).

**However**, when I consider your code details. You also bind the **CommandParameter** to *DogID*. I suppose *DogID* is defined in Dog model. Then **Command** and **CommandParameter** have different BindingContext. That may cause contradictions if set the BindingContext of StackLayout to ViewModel, right?  (If I misunderstand you, please overlook the following)

So I may give another solution, that is [Xamarin.Forms Relative Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings):

```
<Button Text="Update"
        Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ViewDogViewModel}}, Path=UpdateDog_Clicked}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding DogID}"/>
```

In this way, the Button Command's  BindingContext is ViewModel while CommandParameter still binds to each dog item in ObservableCollection.

Hope it works.

Comment: Also for IsVisible property,  ```IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"```. We also have to consider the BindingContext for it. I suppose it's also defined in Dog model?

Comment: IsVisible is defined in there. Your answer lead me down the right path, I appreciate it!. I ended up creating a static resource for the dogviewmodel and using that for the individual button command source

Comment: Glad you solved it! Happy coding!